# Audio source with multiple sound files

Tags: unity, audio

I am limited in the number of audio sources I can add. Is it possible to use a single audio source and then rotate between a collection of audio files. This is for an avatar for VRChat so scripting is not an option as scripts will be removed at build time. It would need to be a feature built into Unity that maybe I am just missing.

Comment: If you are not allowed custom scipts, how are you going to determinate which audio file should be played?

Comment: about the feature built into Unity - you have an editor scripting create the one you need.

Comment: Correct, cannot use scripts. I recognize that it just may not be possible, but I have been wrong in the past and there have been secret tricky loop holes to get things to work in VRC in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Put this script into the folder named Editor and you will get list with audioClips in your inspector. Set slider to count of elements and empty slots appear.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;


[CustomEditor(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class AudioSourceEditor : Editor
{
    public List<AudioClip> audioClips;

    [Obsolete]
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Audio Clips:");
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        {
            int count = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider("Count", audioClips.Count, 0, 10);
            if (count != audioClips.Count)
            {
                audioClips.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    audioClips.Add(null);
                }
            }
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        foreach (AudioClip audioClip in audioClips)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(audioClip, typeof(AudioClip));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This code adds a list in the inspector where you can assign multiple audio clips, but those clips are not serialized as part of the `AudioSource`, and do not survive into a built game or exported asset.

Comment: OP wrote they are using VRChat. They have the requirements listed here: https://creators.vrchat.com/avatars/whitelisted-avatar-components Since AudioSourceEditor is not AudioSource, it will be stripped and the audioclip is missing in the end

Comment: Correct, cannot use scripts. I recognize that it just may not be possible, but I have been wrong in the past and there have been secret tricky loop holes to get things to work in VRC in the past.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can add to your script collection of AudioClips and then play them via audiosource.

```
[SerializeField] List<AudioClip> clips;
IEnumerator Start()
{
 AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
 for(int i = 0;iclips.Count();i++)
    {
    audio.clip = clips[i];
    audio.Play();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(audio.clip.length);
    i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Except you can't use scripts

Comment: Please ensure you've read and understood the whole question, including "scripting is not an option as scripts will be removed at build time"

Comment: I understud AudioSource it is a script. It for some reason you cant use Monobehaviour directtly then  you can modify it as EditorExtension script and add same logic I described.

Comment: Correct, cannot use scripts. I recognize that it just may not be possible, but I have been wrong in the past and there have been secret tricky loop holes to get things to work in VRC in the past.